# getting credentials returned by AWS STS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am having an EC2 instance assigned to an instance profile. The instance profile have permission to assume a cross-account role (say, Account B)

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_ID:role/admin"
```

--role-session-name "Admin_in_acc_B"

by running this command, it will return a temporary security credentials including the session token. Now it comes to how to make use of the information to inject it into the environment variables so that the CLI will be able to run tasks (ec2-describe-instances) on Account B.

```js
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
export EC2_HOME=/usr/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=

export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=

PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin

ec2-describe-instances
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can have the CLI do this all under the hood for you if you use config file. For example, if your credentials file (~/.aws/credentials) looks like this (setup via `aws configure`):

```
[assume-role-source-credentials]
aws_access_key_id = akid
aws_secret_access_key = skid
```

And your config file (~/.aws/config) looks like this:

```
[profile assume-role-profile]
source_profile = assume-role-source-credentials
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::Account_B_ID:role/admin
role_session_name = Admin_in_acc_B
region = us-west-2
```

The CLI would then assume the role automatically, caching and refreshing them to reduce the number of calls to assume role. Note that you'll need to change up those profiles to match your exact configuration (particularly the region).

More docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#using-aws-iam-roles).

Comment: the EC2 was created with instance profile attached. We don't want to hardcode the credentials onto the credential file. The problem arise when it come asks for the source credentials which is a renewable token itself

Comment: The `role_session_name = Admin_in_acc_B` parameter saved my life. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned solution "assume-role-profile" without hardcoded credentials, setting everything on the fly:

You create the profile with assumed role:

```
aws configure --profile assume-role-profile set role_arn arn:aws:iam::Account_B_ID:role/admin
```

To give credentials to the new profile, you must use one of the following lines:

1. `aws configure --profile assume-role-profile set source_profile default`
2. `aws configure --profile assume-role-profile set credential_source Ec2InstanceMetadata`
3. `aws configure --profile assume-role-profile set credential_source EcsContainer`

Line 1 was correct on my personal pc, because I used the default profile.

Line 2 should be correct in your case, using an EC2 Instance with an instance profile (correct wording: the instance has a role)

Line 3 was correct when I tested the code with AWS CodeBuild. The new profile used the credentials of the codepipeline-role.

Afterwards, you may use the new profile, example:

```
aws --profile assume-role-profile ec2 describe-instances
```

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#using-aws-iam-roles

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, rather than using individual commands such as `ec2-describe-instances`, you should use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

This AWS CLI allows credentials to be specified in several ways, including:

- Environment variables (as you have done above)
- Profiles (created via the `aws configure` command and activated via `--profile`

Therefore, you could:

- Call `assume-role` to retrieve credentials
- [Store them in the credentials file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#cli-aws-help-config-vars), eg by using `aws configure --profile foo`
- Then simply call commands such as `aws ec2 describe-instances --profile foo`